# Knapsack problem formulation

Tags: vqe, optimization, hamiltonian

I would like to use a knapsack problem formulation based on Lucas [paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2014.00005). Namely, I try to implement the following math formula for Hamiltonian $H =H_A + H_B$, where
$$H_{B} = -B\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}x_{i};
H_{A} = A(1-\sum_{j=0}^{M-1}2^{j}y_{j}+(c+1-2^{M})y_{M}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}x_{i})^{2}\,.$$

I implemented it using sympy (imported as sp):

```python
    def knapsack(values, weights, capacity, A, B):  
    
    n = len(values)
    M = math.ceil(math.log2(capacity))
    
    # Define the variables
    x = [sp.Symbol(f'x{i}') for i in range(n)]
    y = [sp.Symbol(f'y{i}') for i in range(M+1)]
    
    # Define the objective function
    HB = -B * sum(values[i] * x[i] for i in range(n))
    HA = A * (1 - sum(2**j * y[j] for j in range(M)) + (capacity+1-2**M)*y[M] - sum(weights[i] * x[i] for i in range(n)))**2
    H = HA + HB
    
    # Expand the objective function
    expanded_H = H.expand()
    
    # Extract linear, quadratic, and constant terms from the expanded objective function
    linear_terms = {str(symbol): coeff for symbol, coeff in expanded_H.as_coefficients_dict().items() if symbol.is_symbol}
    
    # Extract quadratic terms
    quadratic_terms = {}
    for term, coeff in expanded_H.as_coefficients_dict().items():
        if isinstance(term, sp.Mul) and len(term.args) == 2:
            v1, v2 = sorted([str(a) for a in term.args])
            if (v1, v2) not in quadratic_terms:
                quadratic_terms[(v1, v2)] = coeff
            else:
                quadratic_terms[(v1, v2)] += coeff
    
    constant = expanded_H.as_coefficients_dict().get(1, 0)
    
    # Create a QuadraticProgram
    qp = QuadraticProgram()
    
    # Add binary variables to the QuadraticProgram
    for var in x + y:
        qp.binary_var(name=str(var))
    
    # Set the objective in QuadraticProgram
    qp.minimize(linear=linear_terms, quadratic=quadratic_terms, constant=constant)
    
    return qp
```

Next, I convert it to the Ising model to get an operator to pass to VQE. Next, I set up VQE to compute the minimum eigenvalue. My question is if the above formulation of the knapsack is correct. When running VQE (on `statevector_simulator`), I get solutions that are more or less random, sometimes suboptimal, sometimes incorrect (breaking capacity constraint). I suppose I missed something in the formulation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I mixed 2 formulations. It solves the problem with algorithm. Regarding randomness it is connected to backend set up on IBM Q.